# sesson doesn't work on php/apache

Tags: php, session

I tried work with session:

for test it I used this code:

```
<?php session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['page1']))
{
    session_register('page'); 
  $_SESSION['page1'] = 1;
  echo "page1-1:".$_SESSION['page1'] ."<br>";
}
else
{
    echo    $_SESSION['page1']++ ;
    echo "page1-2:".$_SESSION['page1'] ."<br>";
}
```

when I refresh the page:

```
page1-1:1
```

and when I refresh the page for second time again I got this msg:

```
page1-1:1
```

But I expect get this:

```
page1-2:2
```

what's wrong?

This is server information:

```
Apache 2.2.27   Running
DirectAdmin 1.45.0  Running
Exim 4.76   Running
MySQL 5.5.37    Running
Named 9.8.2rc1  Running
ProFTPd 1.3.4b  Running
sshd    Running
dovecot 2.2.12  Running
Php 5.3.28  Installed
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: [session_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) is deprecated !

Comment: Works for me.  As @ToKeN said, take out `session_register`.  Also remove the echo in front of `echo $_SESSION[page1]++;`.

Comment: Tnx for answers but doesn't work. in php.ini reporting in enable but I do not get any error....also I remove session_register...but doesn't work.

Comment: After hours,Finally I got my browsers doesn't accepting any cookies...!